# Exclude webresources from obfuscating with babel?

Tags: c#, msbuild, obfuscation, babeljs, webresource

I'm obfuscating a DLL which contains an embedded webresource, however when I try to add it to the page using ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource I get a YSOD

Web resource 'NameSpace.JsFileName.js' was not found.

I'm obfuscating my DLL via a MSBuild script. I've tried setting ResourceEncryption to false but with no luck, and have also tried adding a Rule to target Resrouces and setting them to exclude but with no luck either.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can prevent my webresources from being obfuscated?

Many thanks

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find away around this by moving the WebResources to their own folder, then targeting a rule at that unique namespace, however I would still like to know if there is a better way to target the resources, and why they aren't affected by the "Resources" targeted rules.